# how to group by a range of column values using continuous distribution in pandas data frame using 'group by' and 'cut' method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, backend

I have a pandas dataframe as below showing min, max and average Sale of  Petroleum Product Light Diesel Oil from which I would like to generate dataframe showing min, max and average Sale of  Petroleum Product for 5 years interval like 2010-2014,2015-2019,.. and so on where the end years are included.

Suppose name for the dataframe below is "lightdiesel_df"

```
   petroleum_product  year  max_sale  min_sale  avg_sale
0   Light Diesel Oil  2014         0         0       0.0
1   Light Diesel Oil  2013         0         0       0.0
2   Light Diesel Oil  2012       258       258     258.0
3   Light Diesel Oil  2011         0         0       0.0
4   Light Diesel Oil  2010       227       227     227.0
5   Light Diesel Oil  2009       238       238     238.0
6   Light Diesel Oil  2008       377       377     377.0
7   Light Diesel Oil  2007       306       306     306.0
8   Light Diesel Oil  2006       179       179     179.0
9   Light Diesel Oil  2005       290       290     290.0
10  Light Diesel Oil  2004        88        88      88.0
11  Light Diesel Oil  2003       577       577     577.0
12  Light Diesel Oil  2002       610       610     610.0
13  Light Diesel Oil  2001      2413      2413    2413.0
14  Light Diesel Oil  2000      3416      3416    3416.0
```

So, basically i want the following output as:

```
petroleum_product   year      min_sale  max_sale  avg_sale
Light Diesel Oil    2010-2014   227     258        242.5
Light Diesel Oil    2005-2009   179     377        278
Light Diesel Oil    2000-2004   88     3416       1420.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Grouper` passing the frequency(5 years) and the parameter **closed= 'left'**, like this:

```
df2['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['year'], format = '%Y')

(df2.groupby(['petroleum_product', pd.Grouper(key = 'year', freq = '5Y', closed = 'left')])
    .agg(
      {'year': lambda x: '-'.join((str(min(x.dt.year)), str(max(x.dt.year)))),
      'max_sale' : 'max',
      'min_sale' : 'min',
      'avg_sale' : 'mean'
    }).reset_index(level= 0).reset_index(drop=True)
)
#output:

    petroleum_product   year        max_sale    min_sale    avg_sale
0   Light Diesel Oil    2000-2004   3416        88          1420.8
1   Light Diesel Oil    2005-2009   377         179         278.0
2   Light Diesel Oil    2010-2014   258         0           97.0
```

Comment: i think `'-'.join(..` is better here :) nice solution bdw +1 also you could use the format param for converting to datetime : `pd.to_datetime(df['year'],format='%Y')` :)

Comment: @anky_91 ty for the tip :)

Comment: @anky_91 I had never seen the 'to_datetime' command working only with the year format. I really appreciate the tip, I learned something new today, thank you :)

Comment: Is it possible to omit the ‘0’ values when calculating average and minimum value of the petroleum_product ? for example : incase, of year between 2010-2014 if we omit the '0' value while calculating min of min_sale we get 227 and avg of avg_sale as 242.5 instead of 97.

Comment: If you transform zeros to NaN before the groupby, I believe the code will do what you want but I'm not on my computer right now to edit the answer :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) after creating bins from the `year` column and `labels` to format according to expected output:

```
bins=[*range(df['year'].min(),df['year'].max()+5)][::5]
#output : [2000, 2005, 2010, 2015]
labels=[f"{a}-{b-1}" for a,b in zip(bins,bins[1::])]
#output: ['2000-2004', '2005-2009', '2010-2014']
s=pd.cut(df['year'],bins,labels=labels,include_lowest=True,right=False)

final=(df.assign(year=s).groupby(['petroleum_product','year'],sort=False,as_index=False)
 .agg({'max_sale':'max', 'min_sale':'min','avg_sale':'mean'}))
```

---

```
  petroleum_product       year  max_sale  min_sale  avg_sale
0  Light Diesel Oil  2010-2014      3416        88    1420.8
1  Light Diesel Oil  2005-2009       377       179     278.0
2  Light Diesel Oil  2000-2004       258         0      97.0
```

Comment: @SuyenShrestha how is the max value for 2010-2014 227? when year 2012 has value 258 (check row 3)

Comment: @SuyenShrestha that means the year column is a string column, convert to int or float first. `df['year']=df['year'].astype(int)` or `df['year']=pd.to_numeric(df['year'],errors='coerce')`

Comment: @SuyenShrestha no problem, if it works please check [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique
I m getting this error don't know why?

Comment: @SuyenShrestha hard to tell without seeing the orig data. may be try [Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59511627/9840637)

Answer (score 0):

please try

pd.cut is used to split df on specific range

```
df['year_range']=pd.cut(df.year, [1999,2004,2009,2015])

df_res=df.groupby(['petroleum_product','year_range']).agg({'max_sale':'max', 
'min_sale':'min','avg_sale':'mean'})
```